# Airflow webserver systemd unit fails without saying why

Tags: airflow, systemd, systemctl

This is my systemd unit file for the airflow webserver:

```
#airflow-webserver.service

[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service
Wants=postgresql.service

[Service]
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.env
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i run

```
$ /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver
```

from the command line the webserver starts up just fine. However when i check the status of my systemd process with

```
$ systemctl status airflow-webserver.service
```

I see this

```
● airflow-webserver.service - Airflow webserver daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-17 02:52:56 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 2010 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow webserver (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2010 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

This is an almost useless 'error code' because it doesn't show me what caused the failure, and I have no way of replicating it from the CLI.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
python 3.8.5
airflow 2.0.1
```

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the full logs with

```
journalctl -u airflow-webserver.service
```

Also note that there are issues with airflow using an EnvironmentFile on Ubuntu 18.

See https://www.ryanmerlin.com/2019/07/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/